# There is no checkbox to moving comments after transforming the answer into a comment

Tags: feature-request, bug, moderator-tools

If I do it from the dashboard (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/dashboard), I can move comments when transforming the answer into a comment.

> [image]

But from the question page (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1162297/15479) I can't do it.

> [image]